# Not sending confirmation email upon Registration in Register.aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity

Used instructions from Account Confirmation and Password Recovery with ASP.NET Identity (C#) as per instructions in Registration code found in Visual Studio 2017 Account folder for project.

Error Message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'UserId not found.'

Point at which it failed:
In **Register.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Owin;
using FHSF_5_DEV.Models;
        :
        :
        :

        protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = UserName.Text, Email = UserEmail.Text };
            IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                string code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);
                string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Email, Request);
         ==>    manager.SendEmail(user.Email, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>.");**
```

Answer (score 0):

The User.Email was used instead of the User.ID. The original code had set up the authentication code with the assumption that the email and the userid/username was the same.